Difference between 当て and はず

君がプレゼントをもらう当てがないって知らせたんだ。
I told (her) that you weren't expecting any presents.

Can I replace 当て with はず in this sentence, and does it change the nuance in any way?

It does change the meaning.
When you say はずがない, you as the speaker think something should not be true based on logic, common sense, your past experience, etc. That particular sentence would mean the speaker thinks there is no way the listener would get a present.
当てがない means the listener has no prospect of getting a present.

I'm not sure I understand the difference you're trying to contrast between "no way the listener would get a present" and "no prospect of getting a present".  I don't have a strong sense of how those really differ.  Is it a perception of one party versus another or something else?

@A.Ellett - Hmm, I see what you are saying. The difference I wanted to convey was that the former is the speaker’s opinion or judgment based on the kind of things I listed, whereas the latter is more about the listener not having anyone to give them a present.

Ah!  That helps clarify.  Thank you.
